# grabbing HTTP GET parameter from url using Box API in python

Tags: python, api, box-api

I am dealing with the Box.com API using python and am having some trouble automating a step in the authentication process.

I am able to supply my API key and client secret key to Box. Once Box.com accepts my login credentials, they supply me with an HTTP GET parameter like

```
'http://www.myapp.com/finish_box?code=my_code&'
```

I want to be able to read and store `my_code` using python. Any ideas? I am new to python and dealing with APIs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a more robust question than it seems, as it exposes some useful functions with web dev in general. You're basically asking how to separate `my_code` in the string `'http://www.myapp.com/finish_box?code=my_code&'`.

Well let's take it in bits and pieces. First of all, you know that you only really need the stuff after the question mark, right? I mean, you don't need to know what website you got it from (though that would be good to save, let's keep that in case we need it later), you just need to know what arguments are being passed back. Let's start with String.split():

```
>>> return_string = 'http://www.myapp.com/finish_box?code=my_code&'

>>> step1 = return_string.split('?')
["http://www.myapp.com/finish_box","code=my_code&"]
```

This will return a list to step1 containing two elements, `"http://www.myapp.com/finish_box"` and `"code=my_code&"`. Well hell, we're there! Let's split the second one again on the equals sign!

```
>>> step2 = step1[1].split("=")
["code","my_code&"]
```

Well lookie there, we're almost done! However, this doesn't really allow any more robust uses of it. What if instead we're given:

```
>>> return_string = r'http://www.myapp.com/finish_box?code=my_code&junk_data=ohyestheresverymuch&my_birthday=nottoday&stackoverflow=usefulplaceforinfo'
```

Suddenly our plan doesn't work. Let's instead break that second set on the `&` sign, since that's what's separating the key:value pairs.

```
step2 = step1[1].split("&")
["code=my_code",
"junk_data=ohyestheresverymuch",
"my_birthday=nottoday",
"stackoverflow=usefulplaceforinfo"]
```

Now we're getting somewhere. Let's save those as a dict, shall we?

```
>>> list_those_args = []
>>> for each_item in step2:
>>>   list_those_args[each_item.split("=")[0]] = each_item.split("=")[1]
```

Now we've got a dictionary in `list_those_args` that contains key and value for every argument the GET passed back to you! Science!

So how do you access it now?

```
>>> list_those_args['code']
my_code
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Another question, how do I grab that url automatically using Python? Once the login is authenticated, the webpage redirects me to `'http://www.myapp.com/finish_box?code=my_code&'`. I have no clue how to access and store this url from Python.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have any idea how this particular API works, so I couldn't tell you. If you have Python code that submits the request, you should be able to use Python to listen for the answer, but I'm not sure how.

A non-automatic workaround would be to prompt for it from the user. Maybe `url = raw_input("Please enter the URL in your browser window: ")` then work on that bit instead. I'm not really sure.

Answer (score 0):

You need a webserver and a cgi-script to do this. I have setup a single python script solution to this to run this. You can see my code at:

https://github.com/jkitchin/box-course/blob/master/box_course/cgi-bin/box-course-authenticate

When you access the script, it redirects you to box for authentication. After authentication, if "code" is in the incoming request, the code is grabbed and redirected to the site where tokens are granted.

You have to setup a .htaccess file to store your secret key and id.